# Why does Spark application takes longer to execute when reading dataset from Cassandra table than local file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code, and the application ends immediately after generating the result.

```
  def textProcess(sc: SparkContext) {

    val baseRDD = sc.textFile("C:\\myDrive\\test.log")    
    val result = baseRDD.map { x => x }.reduce((accum, current) => accum)
    println(result)
    sc.close()   
  }
```

But when I run the below code against Cassandra with ***spark-cassandra-connector***,the application ends only after some 10 seconds delay.

```
  def dbProcess(sc: SparkContext) {

    val baseRDD = sc.cassandraTable("local_test", "configurations")
    val result = baseRDD.map { x => x.getString("keyname") }.reduce((accum,current) => accum)
    println(result)
    sc.close()    
  }
```

Version Details

Spark version is 1.6.x

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My question here is , why this delay when dealing with **spark-cassandra-connector**? is there any way to avoid this delay? or is this a version problem?(I tried with few other versions but the result is intact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this delay when dealing with spark-cassandra-connector?

Basically, the difference boils down to the following two lines:

```
sc.textFile("C:\\myDrive\\test.log")
```

and

```
sc.cassandraTable("local_test", "configurations")
```

The former is a relatively cheap access to a local file while the latter accesses a remote Cassandra cluster that's a quite heavy network-wise operation.

Leaving a Cassandra cluster's performance aside, network access is certainly more time-consuming than accessing a local file, *isn't it?*

Comment: yes it makes sense. so this delay would increase if my cluster size grows?

Comment: It depends on how Cassandra handles new nodes and adding new nodes may not necessarily impact performance of any cassandra client, Spark including.

Comment: Okay.Thank you @Jacek Laskowski